# SGE pass queue dependent argument to determine which compiler to use

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I am using a cluster that has AMD and Intel nodes on separate queues and is using SGE 8.1.9. Is it possible to determine which queue a job is being sent to and pass it as argument to a bash script to determine which compiler to use. This is for computational computing btw.

Comment: sorry I meant computational research, not computing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.